# TensorFlow: alternate between datasets of different output shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to use `tf.Dataset` for a 3D image CNN where the shape of the 3D image fed into it from the training set and the validation set are different (training: (64, 64, 64), validation: (176, 176, 160)). I didn't even know this was possible, but I'm recreating this network based on a paper, and using the classic `feed_dict` method the network indeed works. For performance reasons (and just to learn) I'm trying to switch the network to use `tf.Dataset` instead.

I have two datasets and iterators built like the following:

```py
def _data_parser(dataset, shape):
        features = {"input": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
                    "label": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string)}
        parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(dataset, features)

        image = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features["input"], tf.float32)
        image = tf.reshape(image, shape + (1,))

        label = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features["label"], tf.float32)
        label = tf.reshape(label, shape + (1,))
        return image, label

train_datasets = ["train.tfrecord"]
train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(train_datasets)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: _data_parser(x, (64, 64, 64)))
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size) # batch_size = 16
train_iterator = train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

val_datasets = ["validation.tfrecord"]
val_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(val_datasets)
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(lambda x: _data_parser(x, (176, 176, 160)))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(1)
val_iterator = val_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
```

[TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator) has examples regarding switching between datasets using `reinitializable_iterator` or `feedable_iterator`, but they all switch between iterators of **same** output shape, which is not the case here.

How should I switch between training set and validation set using `tf.Dataset` and `tf.data.Iterator` in my case then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply provide unspecified (`None`) values for the shape on the axes where the dimension do not match. E.g.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(np.zeros((64, 64, 64), np.float32)).repeat().batch(4)
validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(np.zeros((176, 176, 160), np.float32)).repeat().batch(1)

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(
    training_dataset.output_types,
    tf.TensorShape([None, None, None, None]))
next_element = iterator.get_next()

training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(training_dataset)
validation_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(validation_dataset)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(training_init_op)
print(sess.run(next_element).shape)
sess.run(validation_init_op)
print(sess.run(next_element).shape)
```